# Is there a way to avoid creating an array in this Julia expression?

Tags: generator, list-comprehension, julia

Is there a way to avoid creating an array in this Julia expression:

```
max((filter(n -> string(n) == reverse(string(n)), [x*y for x = 1:N, y = 1:N])))
```

and make it behave similar to this Python generator expression:

```
max(x*y for x in range(N+1) for y in range(x, N+1) if str(x*y) == str(x*y)[::-1])
```

Julia version is 2.3 times slower then Python due to array allocation and N*N iterations vs. Python's N*N/2.

**EDIT**

After playing a bit with a few implementations in Julia, the fastest loop style version I've got is:

```
function f(N)   # 320ms for N=1000  Julia 0.2.0 i686-w64-mingw32
    nMax = NaN
    for x = 1:N, y = x:N
        n = x*y 
        s = string(n)
        s == reverse(s) || continue
        nMax < n && (nMax = n)
    end 
    nMax
end
```

but an improved functional version isn't far behind (only 14% slower or significantly faster, if you consider 2x larger domain):

```
function e(N)   # 366ms for N=1000  Julia 0.2.0 i686-w64-mingw32
    isPalindrome(n) = string(n) == reverse(string(n))
    max(filter(isPalindrome, [x*y for x = 1:N, y = 1:N]))
end
```

There is 2.6x unexpected performance improvement by defining `isPalindrome` function, compared to original version on the top of this page.

Comment: Nice work. You can just write `filter(isPalindrome, ...)` here.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski Thanks, it looks much nicer now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have talked about allowing the syntax

```
max(f(x) for x in itr)
```

as a shorthand for producing each of the values `f(x)` in one coroutine while computing the max in another coroutine. This would basically be shorthand for something like this:

```
max(@task for x in itr; produce(f(x)); end)
```

Note, however, that this syntax that explicitly creates a task already works, although it is somewhat less pretty than the above. Your problem can be expressed like this:

```
max(@task for x=1:N, y=x:N
    string(x*y) == reverse(string(x*y)) && produce(x*y)
end)
```

With the hypothetical producer syntax above, it could be reduced to something like this:

```
max(x*y if string(x*y) == reverse(string(x*y) for x=1:N, y=x:N)
```

While I'm a fan of functional style, in this case I would probably just use a for loop:

```
m = 0
for x = 1:N, y = x:N
    n = x*y
    string(n) == reverse(string(n)) || continue
    m < n && (m = n)
end
```

Personally, I don't find this version much harder to read and it will certainly be quite fast in Julia. In general, while functional style can be convenient and pretty, if your primary focus is on performance, then explicit for loops are your friend. Nevertheless, we should make sure that John's max/filter/product version works. The for loop version also makes other optimizations easier to add, like Harlan's suggestion of reversing the loop ordering and exiting on the first palindrome you find. There are also faster ways to check if a number is a palindrome in a given base than actually creating and comparing strings.

As to the general question of "getting flexible generators and list comprehensions in Julia", the language already has

1. A general high-performance iteration protocol based on the start/done/next functions.
2. Far more powerful multidimensional array comprehensions than most languages. At this point, the only missing feature is the `if` guard, which is complicated by the interaction with multidimensional comprehensions and the need to potentially dynamically grow the resulting array.
3. Coroutines (aka tasks) which allow, among other patterns, the producer-consumer pattern.

Python has the `if` guard but doesn't worry about comprehension performance nearly as much – if we're going to add that feature to Julia's comprehensions, we're going to do it in a way that's both fast and interacts well with multidimensional arrays, hence the delay.

**Update:** The `max` function is now called `maximum` (`maximum` is to `max` as `sum` is to `+`) and the generator syntax and/or filters work on master, so for example, you can do this:

```
julia> @time maximum(100x - x^2 for x = 1:100 if x % 3 == 0)
  0.059185 seconds (31.16 k allocations: 1.307 MB)
2499
```

Once 0.5 is out, I'll update this answer more thoroughly.

Comment: How about using all of that metaprogramming goodness in Julia to translate `max(x*y if string(x*y) == reverse(string(x*y) for x=1:N, y=x:N)` directly into a loop you wrote above and avoid coroutine call overhead and glue logic. Is that feasible?

Comment: Another reason for using a functional style is correctness guarantee. When you write a piece of imperative code, you have to verify that it's correct and it is easy to get complacent. I know that you are a busy man these days, but the loop you wrote has 2 problems: initial value should be `NaN` and `max = n` should be `nMax = max(n, nMax)`. OTAH, the declarative (functional) version one line above is free of these problems. I don't mean to nitpick, I only mean to illustrate the point: declarative `max` is a max, imperative max implementation is incorrect until proven otherwise.

Comment: I added a benchmark of best loop version and modified functional version, which is only 16% slower.

Comment: Metaprogramming doesn't buy you new syntax or automatic translations of syntaxes, it only allows you to write things like macros. This hypothetical syntax isn't a macro – it's an entirely new language feature including new syntax which isn't currently valid Julia.

Answer (score 6):

There are two questions being mixed together here: (1) can you filter a list comprehension mid-comprehension (for which the answer is currently no) and (2) can you use a generator that doesn't allocate an array (for which the answer is partially yes). Generators are provided by the Iterators package, but the Iterators package seems to not play well with `filter` at the moment. In principle, the code below should work:

```
max((x, y) -> x * y,
    filter((x, y) -> string(x * y) == reverse(string(x * y)),
           product(1:N, 1:N)))
```

Comment: Is `product` function available? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. There aren't currently filters in Julia array comprehensions. See discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/550).

In this particular case, I'd suggest just nested `for` loops if you want to get faster computation.

(There might be faster approaches where you start with `N` and count backwards, stopping as soon as you find something that succeeds. Figuring out how to do that correctly is left as an exercise, etc...)

Comment: I've seen that thread. Is there any hope for getting flexible generators or list comprehensions in Julia? Are they too far from Matlab paradigm? As far as changing the algorithm, it is a different exercise, beyond the scope of my question.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is now possible (using Julia 0.5.0)

```
isPalindrome(n::String) = n == reverse(n)
fun(N::Int) =  maximum(x*y for x in 1:N for y in x:N if isPalindrome(string(x*y)))
```

I'm sure there are better ways that others can comment on. Time (after warm-up):

```
julia> @time fun(1000);
   0.082785 seconds (2.03 M allocations: 108.109 MB, 27.35% gc time)
```